# haskell; _ [] = ... doesn't match (2,1) []

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
combineb :: (Integer,Integer) -> [Integer] -> Integer
comnineb _ [] = 0
combineb x (l:ls) = l + (combineb x ls)
```

Program error: pattern match failure: combineb (2,1) []

Could you please help me, why doesnt _ [] match (2,1) [] ?

btw. I know that I'm actually never using the first Paremter in this function...

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think `combineb` is exactly a great name for a function. In properly camelCased names with suggestive meaning, typos like the one that caused your problem are easier to spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo -- `comnineb` instead of `combineb` in the second line of your program.

Comment: No problem - it happens to me all the time!